# How to target app releases in closed tracks to organizations?

Tags: google-play-console, android-management-api

I published a private app in closed tracks to my own organization using Play Console, explained [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139#publishprivate).

Under **Pricing & distribution -> User Programs -> Managed Google Play** it says:

> This app is privately targeted to 1 organization.
>
> You can also target app releases in closed tracks to organizations. Manage closed tracks or Learn more

Under **Release management -> App Releases -> Manage testers** I added my organization.

Still, when setting my app to force install in my Android Management Api policy for my devices, my private app won't get installed and is also not visible to my dedicated devices using that policy.

Previously, I published a private app as a production release to my organization and everything works like a charm.
So what exactly do I have to do to target my organization in a closed track release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised that you just have to add the "releaseTrackId", which can be found in the URL of the Play Console page that displays the app’s track information, to my application json object inside the policy. As it says [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications) and [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#ApplicationPolicy)

> List of the app’s track IDs that a device belonging to the enterprise can access. If the list contains multiple track IDs, devices receive the latest version among all accessible tracks. **If the list contains no track IDs, devices only have access to the app’s production track.** More details about each track are available in AppTrackInfo.

So basically in my applications array in the particular policy I just had to add the "releaseTrackId" of my closed track app in the "accessibleTrackIds" array.

```
"applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "some.package.com.closedtrackapp",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "accessibleTrackIds": [
        "myreleaseTrackId"
      ]
    }    
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this API [Custom App API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api). Publish your private app to your organisation and wait around 10min till the app is approved before you can install to your enrolled device.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, but the API looks quite interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you also need to add the track Id of the closed track to your policy:
See [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#ApplicationPolicy) for ApplicationPolicy

```
{
  "packageName":"<package id>",
  "installType":"PREINSTALLED",
  "accessibleTrackIds":[
    "<track id>"
   ]
}
```

The track id is found on the play console URL (releaseTrackId parameter)